# How to use USB-serial and debug simultaneously via ONLY one USB port in Android?

Tags: android, flutter, debugging, usb, uart

I have successfully used the usb-serial package in Flutter on Windows to communicate data via UART with an external custom device.

However, I'm looking to port this functionality to Android. How can I communicate and debug simultaneously on an Android device that has only one USB port?

Could someone provide guidance on this?
Thank you in advance for your help.

--
I would like to know how to simultaneously transfer data and debug—whether it involves using a USB hub or setting up a virtual device to communicate with the physical USB-serial connection? Alternatively, is it only possible to use Wi-Fi, ADB, or similar methods for this purpose?

Comment: USB connection can have multi endpoints. In the Linux (Android) this is done via `libcomposite` kernel module and respective configuration via ConfigFS.

Comment: as you mentioned you can use wifi ADB for debugging and USB port for transferring data